# GAE: is leaseTask in pull queue an asynchronous call?

Tags: google-app-engine, asynchronous, task-queue, pull-queue

I would like to use `GAE` `Task Queue` (`pull queue`) as a message queue in an app.
The `receiveMessage` calls in other message queue services (Ex. `AmazonSQS`) are asynchronous calls, providing web scalability to the apps.

The `pull queue` have the call: `leaseTask` instead of `receiveMessage` and I would like to know whether this call is asynchronous, as I need to provide web scalability to my app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

leaseTasks returns a task (or tasks) hence it cannot be asynchronous.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That means can t I use asynchronous message consumption in my app, as GAE does not allow spawning new threads for apps running on JVM?

Comment: @DuliniAtapattu: CMIIW, but I thought we could [spawn background threads](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview#background_threads) if our code runs in the backend.